# TideSDK: Getting the Hello World example app to work

Tags: api, tidesdk

I'm on Windows 7 64bit and I'm following the [Getting Started Tutorial](http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/guide/getting_started). So far I've:

1. Downloaded TideSDK-1.3.1-beta-win-x86.zip
2. Extracted the 3 folders it contains (modules, runtime, and sdk) to C:/ProgramData/TideSDK/
3. Downloaded and installed Imagemagick
4. Downloaded and installed Wix 3.0
5. Downloaded and installed TideSDK-Developer-1.4.2-win-x86.msi
6. Cloned using Git: https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK-HelloWorld
7. Opened TideSDK Developer tool.
8. Clicked "Import Project" and selected the cloned Git repository, hit OK. ([Screenshot](http://puu.sh/1CDng))
9. Clicked "Test & Package" tab, and then clicked "Launch App" button. ([Screenshot](http://puu.sh/1CDnI))

TideSDK Developer tool says "Preparing to package and launch desktop app. One moment..." but it never does do anything beyond that. The tutorial says I [should see this](http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/guides/getting_started/developer_running.jpg), but I don't.

There are no errors anywhere that I can see. What can I do to get this Hello World app working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to get TideSDK to work. However I found something that worked even better: node-webkit.

> "node-webkit is an app runtime based on `Chromium` and `node.js`. You can write native apps in HTML and Javascript with node-webkit. It also lets you to call Node.js modules directly from DOM and enables a new way of writing native applications with all Web technologies."

https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit